# How can I enable refreshing dynamic routes in my Next.js app without using `getStaticPaths`?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, serverless

In my Next.js application, I'm having the well-known problem of being able to navigate via `<Link>` to dynamic routes, but when I refresh that page, I get a 404 error since the page was rendered client-side. The app is serverless, so a custom server isn't an option, and the paths I need can indeed be fetched from an API, but that API requires token authentication first so I can't populate the paths I need to pre-render with `getStaticPaths` either. This app is dynamic, and the pages I'm trying to access through dynamic routes use a lot of Client-Side Rendering anyways, so I don't have a problem with pushing rendering over to the client. I just need to know how to do that if that's the solution, and those two solutions (custom server and `getStaticPaths`) are the only two I've been able to find.

EDIT: I also use `next export` to deploy.

Comment: Do you use next export for your app or next start?

Comment: I use next export. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Not possible then. Next export generates a static site hence the index.html file. You need to have a server up and running then those static paths and props will get fetched depending on your revalidate time.